# If I sort an array and then loop through it twice using a nested loop, would the time complexity be O(n^2*log(n)) or just O(n^2)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I wrote an algorithm that takes in an array and a targetSum integer and then outputs an array of arrays of all triplet values that add to the targetSum. I'm just not sure if it runs in O(N^2*log(N)) or O(N^2) time. Would the sorting be negligible in comparison to the nested loop or no?

```
function threeNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const triplets = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 2; i++) {
    let left = i + 1;
    let right = array.length - 1;
    while (left < right) {
      const currentSum = array[i] + array[left] + array[right];
      if (currentSum === targetSum) {
        triplets.push([array[i], array[left], array[right]]);
        left++;
        right--;
      } else if (currentSum < targetSum) {
        left++;
      } else if (currentSum > targetSum) {
        right--;
      }
    }
  }
  return triplets;
}
```

Comment: It would just be `O(n²)` as `O(g(x) + f(x)) = max { O(g(x)), O(f(x)) }`. Meaning for your example `O(O(n²) + O(n * log n)) = O(n²)`. Also see [Wikipedia for Sum on Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the sort is done *outside* the nested loops, given that the nested loops have a dominating runtime (`n²` is greater than `n log n`), the sort is ignorable. When adding a fixed number of big-O steps, the overall big-O is the max of the individual steps, not the product of it. Thus, the big-O runtime is `O(n²)` (the sort is irrelevant to the final big-O).